# Why do chloroform and benzene exhibit negative deviation from Raoult's law?

Tags: solutions, intermolecular-forces, polarity

Chloroform is a polar molecule, and benzene is nonpolar. Shouldn't the chloroform-chloroform and benzene-benzene intermolecular forces be stronger than chloroform-benzene interactions (like dissolves like), which would result in a positive deviation from Raoult's law?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6955/deviation-from-raoults-law-because-of-adhesive-and-cohesive-forces

Answer (score 7):

This is because when these liquids are mixed, H-bonding type interactions are formed between hydrogen atom of chloroform (partial positive charge due to 3 Cl atoms) and 'pi' electron cloud of benzene ring.﻿
Thus, chloroform-benzene interactions are stronger than chloroform-chloroform and benzene-benzene interactions.

Comment: Then, why does acetone and benzene show positive deviation? Doesn't acetone (being a polar molecule) form hydrogen bonds with the "pi" electron cloud of the benzene ring?

Comment: @AdityaKumarPanda such an interaction would require availability of a hydrogen bonded to an electronegative atom, which is absent in acetone.

Comment: @ShivanshJaiswal Yeah, I've got it. Thanks!